# Copying node_modules when building node app using babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am trying to use es6 in my node 4.4.6 app transpiling using babel. I added a step to my npm script

```
"compile": "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js --preset es2015 --out-dir dist/ . --source-maps",
```

to do the transpile but was getting too many errors in my node_modules to deal with. So for Question #1, is it a normal practice to just do the transpile on your src and then copy the node_modules folder?

I gave this a shot using this .babelrc file, but babel still wanted to transpile my node_modules

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "ignore": [
    "*-compiled*",
    "*.js.map*",
    "node_modules*"
  ]
}
```

and for Question #2, if it is normal, what is wrong with my .babelrc file, such that it is still trying to process my node_modules?

anyways, any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Normally you'd have your source in a subfolder, so that you could compile everything in there and not have to worry about `node_modules`.

Comment: Also FYI you can just do `babel` instead of `./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js`

Comment: thanks @loganfsmyth . for assets that are not javascript , like html templates, do you, a separate step in your script, you copy over those assets to your /dist folder ?  also are your tests side by side with each file or are they in a separate tests folder, which is outside the main app?

Comment: I'd probably consider the app to be the whole root folder, so you'd have a subfolder for ES6, one for assets, and so on, and then one for the compiled ES5 from Babel.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks!